# How to set a keyboard shortcut to activate an existing Internet connection

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, internet

I usually click on the connection item in the connections drop-down menu in the upper right corner of the screen to activate my Internet connection. Is there a way to set a custom keyboard shortcut to get the same result? Hopefully a single command that I could insert among my other Custom keyboard shortcuts in System Settings > Keyboard.

Thank you very much, have a good day.

P.S.: the matter continues here: 
[How to set a single shortcut to switch an Internet connection on and off](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328890/how-to-set-a-single-shortcut-to-switch-an-internet-connection-on-and-off)
.

Comment: Doesn't it connect automatically to the internet?

Comment: No, I prefer to turn the connection on when I need it and then to turn it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Please read the whole thing before modifying anything. Ask away if you have doubts with some step.*

### Approach 1: Using `nmcli`

Open **Keyboard** and add a custom shortcut. For the command type `nmcli nm enable true`, that will activate the Network Manager (if your network is set to *Automatic* it should connect immediately). If you want a shortcut for disconnecting, the command would be `nmcli nm enable false`.

For more information about `nmcli` and other ways to accomplish what you want, read `man nmcli`.

### Approach 2: Using `/etc/network/interfaces`

If you'd rather activating/configuring your internet connection manually, you can skip Network Manager and configure the file `/etc/network/interfaces` to your needs.

---

First disconnect from the internet and disable Network Manager:

```
sudo stop network-manager
echo "manual" | sudo tee /etc/init/network-manager.override
```

---

Open `/etc/network/interfaces` in an editor:

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

and add the following:

```
# The wireless network interface 
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
  wpa-ssid  wireless_network_name
  wpa-psk   wireless_passphrase
```

(I am assuming you are dealing with a wireless connection, please do clarify if I'm wrong. I'm also assuming you only have one wireless card.)

---

Now to make sure it is not so easy to see your passphrase:

```
sudo chmod 600 /etc/network/interfaces
```

---

Modify your sudoers file so you can run `ifup` and `ifdown` *without* password

```
sudo visudo
```

type `i`, go to the last line (with the arrow keys) and type

```
your_username  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/ifup wlan0, /sbin/ifdown wlan0
```

type <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then type `:wq`.

---

Now test it by running `sudo ifup wlan0`. Try opening a web page on the browser.

If that worked, now all you need to do is create a shortcut, so open **Keyboard** and add a custom shortcut. For the command type `sudo ifup wlan0`.

You might also want to create a shortcut to disconnect. For that the command would be `sudo ifdown wlan0`.

---

If you want to reactivate Network Manager, you must first delete/comment the lines you added to `/etc/network/interfaces`. Then run:

```
sudo rm /etc/init/network-manager.override
sudo start network-manager
```

---

**Remark:**

If you are up to it, you can install `gksu` and for the shortcut command use `gksudo ifup wlan0`. This way you can skip the editing of the sudoers file (which I wouldn't recommend if you are in unfamiliar territory). With this method you would have to type your password, though.

### References

1. [Arstechnica: Howto deal with Network Manager completely from the command line](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=1163023)
2. [Ubuntu Help: NetworkManager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager)

Comment: It's a mobile broadband connection via USB dongle. Is there a "compromise" between this solution and the presence of the Network connections indicator/menu? I like it and I'd like not to remove Ubuntu standard elements, just adding the shortcut to have both types of access, mouse click and keyboard shortcut (also because, should I reinstall Ubuntu in the future, I'd like to keep the number of personalizations as low as possible). Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your precious help Edwin. I'll choose the first approch and read the nmcli manual and references to see if there's a way to activate a specific connection (sometimes I have two different of them and they are not set to Automatic). I'll also look for 1) how to set in a single statement two commands (how to combine "Enable mobile broadband network" command and "Connection name" execution) and 2) how to make only one shortcut to activate and deactivate the connection, with a conditional construct, always in a single statement. I hope it will be easy. Thank you again.